# Mysql Right Join returns unnessary result

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am having problem with one of my query and cant find solution in my head i tried in many ways but couldn't come to the desired result. here is my table structure:

```
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field          | Type          | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| accounts_id    | int(11)       | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| portfolio_id   | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| contest_id     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| user_id        | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| company_id     | int(11)       | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| buy_price      | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| buy_amount     | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| buy_commision  | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| buy_date       | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sell_price     | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sell_amount    | int(11)       | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sell_commision | decimal(10,2) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| sell_date      | date          | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
+----------------+---------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I want to find realized gain from buy and sell of each, so i used this query:

```
SELECT
a.company_id,
a.buy_price,
a.buy_amount,
a.buy_commision,
a.buy_date,
a.sell_price,
a.sell_amount,
a.sell_commision,
a.sell_date,
(((a.sell_amount*a.sell_price)-(a.sell_amount*a.sell_price)*.5/100)-((b1.buy_price*a.sell_amount)+    (b1.buy_price*a.sell_amount)*.5/100)) as realized
FROM contest_accounts AS a
RIGHT join contest_accounts as b1
on a.portfolio_id = b1.portfolio_id
WHERE a.user_id = 1
AND a.contest_id = 2;
```

which gives me results like this:
    http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d8e2c/2

but i want result like this:

```
 +------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+----- -----------+------------+-------------+
 | company_id | buy_price | buy_amount | buy_commision | buy_date   | sell_price | sell_amount | sell_commision | sell_date  | realized    |
          +------------+-----------+------------+---------------+------------+------------+-------------+-----      -----------+------------+-------------+
 |          1 |      6.80 |        300 |         10.20 | 2014-03-15 |       NULL |        NULL      |           NULL | NULL       |        NULL |
 |          1 |      NULL |       NULL |          NULL | NULL       |       6.80 |         200      |           6.80 | 2014-03-15 | -13.6000000 |
 |          1 |      NULL |       NULL |          NULL | NULL       |       6.80 |         100      |           3.40 | 2014-03-15 |  -6.8000000 |
 |          1 |      6.80 |        100 |          3.40 | 2014-03-15 |       NULL |        NULL     |           NULL | NULL       |        NULL |
 |          1 |      NULL |       NULL |          NULL | NULL       |       6.50 |         100      |           3.25 | 2014-03-18 | -36.6500000 |
            3 |     20.10 |        200 |         20.10 | 2014-03-15 |       NULL |        NULL |           NULL | NULL       |        NULL |
 |          3 |      NULL |       NULL |          NULL | NULL       |      19.80 |         100      |           9.90 | 2014-03-16 | -49.9500000 |
```

The main problem is current query returns so many null but i want result which has buy date or realized gain not so many null, i know i messed with the join but don't know how can achieve my desired result. please check the sqlfiddle with sample data and my query result.

Answer (score 2):

Add the condition `buy_date IS NOT NULL` to the where clause. That will give you only record where buy_date is not null. You can add similar conditions for other records too.

And I think you can change your `RIGHT JOIN` to an `INNER JOIN`. You only use `RIGHT JOIN` when it is possible that no matching record for `b` exists in `a`. In this case, there is always a record in a, because you already implicitly filter out the other cases by having the condition `a.user_id = 1` in the where clause.
In effect, changing to `INNER JOIN` will not change the outcome, but might speed up the query and make it a little more readable (to my taste).

Comment: no luck if i set not null then realized comes with null value, also i changed to inner join but the result didn't changed.